# Как сделать авто обновление программы python?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Можете ли вы предложить варианты, как сделать автоматическое обновление скомпилированной программы? Планируется распространять программу через установщик, например, через inno setup. Я нашел вариант с отдельной программой, которая запустит uninstaller, загрузит новый установщик и запустить его.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите автоматически обновлять своё ПО есть следующие варианты:

1. Вы можете использовать инструменты, такие как [PyUpdater](https://www.pyupdater.org/usage-client/).
2. Вы можете использовать платформы распространения программного обеспечения, такие как Steam, GitHub, Docker или другие аналогичные платформы, которые предоставляют возможность автоматического обновления для программы.
3. Вы можете создать собственный механизм обновления для вашей программы. Например, вы можете создать программу, которая проверяет доступность новых версий программы, скачивает новые версии и запускает установщик.